# ansprechen and angehen

Tags: word-usage

When are : ansprechen" and "angehen" interchangeable? I read that ansprechen is for addressing a person and angehen is for addressing a problem, but I find plenty of examples where this does not hold.

Comment: Could you provide some of these examples where you identified a different usage?

Answer (score 5):

> Ein Problem ansprechen => to mention a problem, to broach a problem

> Ein Problem angehen => to approach a problem (in the sense of beginning to solve it, not just talking about it)

> Eine Person ansprechen => to address a person

> Eine Person angehen =>
>
> 1. to concern a person ("Was Anna angeht, ... " means "Concerning Anna, ...")
> 2. to lay into a person (attacking/assaulting them)

From the top of my head, I don't see any context where "ansprechen" and "angehen" would be directly interchangable.

Comment: Used in the sense of 2. one frequently says "eine Person hart angehen".